# sparql with brackets in subject

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

I am trying to query dbpedia using sparql and running into a problem with brackets in the subject name. This query runs but returns nothing. If I try it on a similar Person without brackets it works.

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT * WHERE
{
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Yves_Saint_Laurent_(designer)> dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract ;
dbpedia-owl:thumbnail ?thumbnail .filter(langMatches(lang(?abstract),"en"))
}
```

I have tried various characters to escape the brackets but nothing seems to works. Is there another way to get the data out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that your problem is related to the fact that 'Yves Saint Laurent' doesn't have the property thumbnail.

Take a look at : [Yves Saint Laurent on dbpedia](http://dbpedia.org/page/Yves_Saint_Laurent_(designer))

This query works :

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT * WHERE
{
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Yves_Saint_Laurent_(designer)>
dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract
filter(langMatches(lang(?abstract),"en"))
}
```

I tested it on : http://dbpedia.org/sparql

Comment: Well spotted, is there any way that I can frame the query so that it returns the abstract  if there isn't a thumbnail?

Comment: @RobSedgwick You mean return the abstract *instead* of the thumbnail, if there's no thumbnail?  Or make each optional? You coul do `select ?a ?t { ... optional { ?s dbpedia-owl:abstract ?a } optional { ?s dbpedia-owl:thumbnail ?t } }` (to make each optional, but still getting both).  Alternatively, you can do the same thing, but add a coalesce into the select to pick the value of the first bound variable:  `select (coalesce(?t,?a) as ?thumbnailOrAbstract) { ... }`.

Comment: that sounds good. I want both fields but if the thumbnail is blank I want an empty string ideally. If the abstract is missing I am not bothered  whether anything is returned or not. Sorry I don't really understand the syntax of your example though (I am an sparql novice) and I couldn't get it to run in Virtuso which is what I use to see the results of sparql.